# Add modal images?

Tags: javascript, css, r, hugo, blogdown

Is it possible to add [modal images](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp) to a blog post? In case is relevant, I'm using the `Vimux/Mainroad` theme.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Hugo pages all become HTML in the end, so anything you can do in HTML, you can do with Hugo. To make it work, your theme needs code for modal images in its template, CSS, and JavaScript files. It doesn't look like the [Mainroad theme](https://github.com/Vimux/Mainroad) supports modal images yet, so you (or someone else) will need to edit it.